# Search in Black Navbar with Bootstrap

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to include a black navbar with a search box using bootstrap as shown here:  http://jsfiddle.net/hYAEQ/410/.  The codes of the css is below.

I don't like how the color of the search box changes when it receives focus.  How can I keep the color of the box the same as it is when it doesn't have focus?

Thank you.

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}

body { padding: 20px; }

.navbar-search {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-search .search-query {
    padding-left: 29px !important;
}

.navbar-search .icon-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 11px;
    background-image: url("http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add these CSS rules, but it may be a pretty heavy-handed approach. I hope it doesn't break anything else in your design :

```
input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    color: #555555 !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG7g/).